# Ms Access - Delete all tables, queries, forms, reports and modules

Tags: vba, ms-access, button

I want to make a self destroyed button in my database, for security reasons. I need to modified my code so it can loop in all my tables, queries, forms, reports, module and delete them. If an error occurred, to move to the next one.

Now I am using the following code, which is an example:

```
 On error Resume Next
 DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "tblExtra"
 DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "tblFinances"
 DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "tblHealth"
 ....
```

As you will see, I am using DoCmd.DeleteObject for each item I want to delete.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code will delete all of the objects, there might be errors along the way so you should still use on error resume next if you want.  It closes the object then deletes:

```
Dim obj As AccessObject

For Each obj In CurrentProject.AllReports
    Debug.Print "Deleting " & obj.Name
    DoCmd.Close acReport, obj.Name, acSaveNo
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acReport, obj.Name
Next

For Each obj In CurrentProject.AllForms
    Debug.Print "Deleting " & obj.Name
    DoCmd.Close acForm, obj.Name, acSaveNo
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acForm, obj.Name
Next

For Each obj In CurrentData.AllTables
    If obj.Name Not Like "MSys*" then
         Debug.Print "Deleting " & obj.Name
         DoCmd.Close acTable, obj.Name, acSaveNo
         DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, obj.Name
    End If
Next

For Each obj In CurrentData.AllQueries
    Debug.Print "Deleting " & obj.Name
    DoCmd.Close acQuery, obj.Name, acSaveNo
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, obj.Name
Next
```

For your reference, and if you want to add more objects to delete, here are the objects in CurrentData:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823195.aspx

and here are the objects in CurrentProject:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835979.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is what I want, but I have found two errors until now.

Comment: 1) if the form is the one where the button is press, the code is getting error

Comment: 2) the first table is MSysAccessStorage and getting error again.

Comment: Indeed be careful of MSys* tables which are system tables built-in to MS Access. Place an if conditional in tables block: `If obj.Name Not Like "MSys*"`. Of course too watch out for object that this code runs from.

Comment: Added msys to the answer, thanks for that Parfait.  Yvette, I don't understand what you mean by "where the button is press".  Are you talking about a form that won't close?

Comment: Thank you both. @Graham I mean that if my form is loaded(the one where the button is), I am getting error. I need to move to the next form if any error found.

Comment: @Graham, thanks for sharing. I have added another answer based on yours, cause I got random errors while iterating through the collections and at the same time deleting the objects.

Answer (score 1):

As for Access 2016, Graham's answer randomly fails (automation error) while deleting objects.

It is safer to delete objects by index, from last to first.
The checkonly parameter is just for testing purposes, in case you erase any important object.

I've tested both solutions in Access 2016 MSO (16.0.8431.2110) 32 bits.

```
Public Sub deleteObjects(Optional ByVal CheckOnly As Boolean = True)

    Dim obj     As AccessObject
    Dim i       As Long

    With CurrentProject
        For i = .AllReports.count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            Set obj = .AllReports(i)
            Debug.Print "Deleting " & obj.Name
            If Not CheckOnly Then
                DoCmd.Close ObjectType:=acReport, ObjectName:=obj.Name, Save:=acSaveNo
                DoCmd.DeleteObject acReport, obj.Name
            End If
        Next

        For i = .AllForms.count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            Set obj = .AllForms(i)
            If obj.Name <> "myImportantForm" Then
                Debug.Print "Deleting " & obj.Name
                If Not CheckOnly Then
                    DoCmd.Close ObjectType:=acForm, ObjectName:=obj.Name, Save:=acSaveNo
                    DoCmd.DeleteObject acForm, obj.Name
                End If
            End If
        Next

        For i = .AllModules.count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            Set obj = .AllModules(i)
            If obj.Name <> "myImportantModule" Then
                Debug.Print "Deleting " & obj.Name
                If Not CheckOnly Then
                    DoCmd.DeleteObject acModule, obj.Name
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With

    With CurrentData
        For i = .AllQueries.count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            Set obj = .AllQueries(i)
            Debug.Print "Deleting " & obj.Name
            If Not CheckOnly Then
                DoCmd.Close ObjectType:=acQuery, ObjectName:=obj.Name, Save:=acSaveNo
                DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, obj.Name
            End If
        Next

        For i = .AllTables.count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            Set obj = .AllTables(i)
            If Not obj.Name Like "MSys*" Then
                Debug.Print "Deleting " & obj.Name
                If Not CheckOnly Then
                    DoCmd.Close ObjectType:=acTable, ObjectName:=obj.Name, Save:=acSaveNo
                    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, obj.Name
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```